# How to count how many times a rule appears in a specific month.Exce;

Tags: worksheet-function

I want to count how many times in a specific month(for example:January) the red cell with the rule: equal or more than 15 days -> red cell , appears. How can I do that?
My table looks like this

```
    A        B
16.02.2013   15
17.01.2012   20
01.02.2013    4
26.04.2012   10
01.01.2012   21
20.04.2012   7
```

The answer for January is **2**

How can I do if I want to make the count by month and year?

Thank you in advance!
Lygia

Answer (score 0):

You can use the countifs function for this.  ([Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx))

Assuming C1 holds start date you want to count from, and C2 holds end date you want to count too.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;">="&C1;A:A;"<="&C2;B:B;">15")
```

Not sure if you can tie the condition directly to the formating rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that entries in ColumnB greater than or equal to `15` have been formatted red. (Which could imply a flaw in @Taemyr's answer, where `>15` should perhaps be `>=15`.)  Also, that the likes of "(for example:January)" implies that a solution that works conveniently for many months would be appreciated, so suggest a PivotTable.

Due to PT constraints, identification of values greater than a cutoff is easier in the source data. In this case should only require filtering to select values that have already been formatted red, and adding a flag, say `x`, to these.

Then the PT could be filtered for `x` only and the ColumnA values (ROWS) Grouped by Years and Months. The sum of VALUES field being Count of B.

[image: SO18507772 example]